# Retrieving raw XML for items with feedparser

Tags: python, xml, rss, atom-feed, feedparser

I'm trying to use feedparser to retrieve some specific information from feeds, but also retrieve the raw XML of each entry (ie.  elements for RSS and  for Atom), and I can't see how to do that. Obviously I could parse the XML by hand, but that's not very elegant, would require separate support for RSS and Atom, and I imagine it could fall out of sync with feedparser for ill-formed feeds. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the current developer of feedparser. Currently, one of the ways you can get that information is to monkeypatch `feedparser._FeedParserMixin` (or edit a local copy of feedparser.py). The methods you'll want to modify are:

- `feedparser._FeedParserMixin.unknown_starttag`
- `feedparser._FeedParserMixin.unknown_endtag`

At the top of each method you can insert a callback to a routine of your own that will capture the elements and their attributes as they're encountered by feedparser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's something useful, but what I intended to do was to retrieve the full XML (including known items) for each item as a way to store them and serve them back in an aggregated feed (for instance). [Actually, I realize this wouldn't be very convenient because items could be in various formats (RSS, Atom, etc.). Maybe it would be a useful addition to feedparser to have a way to generate back XML for items in the various formats that feedparser can parse...]